# sudo apt update always finds updates-issue

Tags: apt

since I cannot find an answer on the internet I will try it here: Always when I run the command

`sudo apt update`

it is always updating the same thing. Output in here:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com eoan InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jtaylor/keepass/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:4 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                                                                                                       
Hit:6 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease                                                                                                    
Get:7 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_19.10 ./ InRelease [2468 B]                                                                             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                        
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Fetched 2468 B in 1s (1873 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

So if I run again

```
sudo apt update
```

then the output is equal. Can somebody help me, or it this normal?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? `apt update` updates the package list from the repositories (servers). If you run `apt upgrade`, the newer packages found through the previous `update` will be downloaded and installed (=upgraded).

Comment: Yeah but as I said, if I run again, again, again and again this command, the output will always be EXACTLY the same. It seems like there is always an update of 2468 bytes.
I remember that just the last line occurred as I ran this command, as I once updated the apt manager.

Comment: That is not normal, especially if "again and again" covers months. Try to choose another download site in the Update-manager settings, eventually "Main Server".

Comment: Okey so I have nothing to worry about? ^^
thanks guys:)

Comment: You have nothing to worry about, everything in order. :) The "update" of 2468B is just the newest package list, telling you that everything is up to date. 
Could you please mark this question as answered? That would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is completely normal. All apt update does is that is updates the package list from the Ubuntu repositories. If there are no updates, then it does not have to update anything.